# How to pluck by key name matching?

Tags: rethinkdb

Say I have the following table:

```
[
  {numberOfRedStripes: 7, numberOfBlueStripes: 6, stars: 50, foo: "bar"},
  {numberOfRedStripes: 1, numberOfBlueStripes: 1, stars: 0, something: "else"}
]
```

How can I use regex in order to pluck only the docs which their KEYS start with the string 'numberOf', so that the result would be:

```
 [
      {numberOfRedStripes: 7, numberOfBlueStripes: 6},
      {numberOfRedStripes: 1, numberOfBlueStripes: 1}
 ]
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
table.map {|row|
  row.pluck(r.args(row.keys().filter{|key| key.match("^numberOf")}))
}
```

Comment: It works, yet in js for example it looks way less readable: table.map(function(row) {return row.pluck(r.args(row.keys().filter(function(key) {return key.match("^numberOf")})))})